# Page Footer not showing in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2008.  I have about 5 pages worth of static text that needs to appear at the top of my report, so I put it in the report header section.  I have a page footer section on the page that shows the page number.  This does not show, and I suspect it has something to do with the long report header.  How can I make the page footer show with a large report header?

Edit: The Page Footer is actually appearing once on the last page.  The Report Header takes up 5 pages and there isn't a page footer on any of those pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved all of my text from the Report Header to the Report Footer, and the page numbers will print.  I will add a subreport to show my detailed data.

Answer (score 2):

Can you split static text between many header (sub)sections (in a way that every section has about pageful of text)? May help.

Comment: I think that is a workaround that I could use.  I am going to keep looking for something a little easier, but I may come back to this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. My report header was very long and the page number only was appearing at last page. The problem was that i had my page number in the Report Footer. Then i realize that i had a Page Footer section and moved the page number there. I also changed the section properties (it had the No Drill down option checked).
Now i have the same big header with the page number on all pages.
Bye

Answer (score 0):

Ken Hammady has a solution for crosstabs at
http://kenhamady.com/cru/archives/87

It can be adapted to work with long texts in textboxes.